# Unable to append rendered text in angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, handlebars.js

My controller:

```
myApp.controller('actionEditController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$sce',function ($scope, $stateParams, $sce) {
    $context = $scope;
    $.get(apiHost + "/action/entity/" + $stateParams.id)
        .success(function (response) {
            angular.module('broConsoleApp', ['ngSanitize']);
            var action = response['RESPONSE'];
            action.params = JSON.parse(action.paramsJson);
            console.log(action);
            var table = $.hbs("/templates/action.hbs", action);
            var el=angular.element(table);
            $scope.content= $sce.trustAsHtml(table);
            console.log(table);
        })
        .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error("Error retrieving action", textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
}])
;
```

My .hbs :

```
<div>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="{{name}}"/>
    <input name="id" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="{{id}}"/>
    <input name="type" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="{{actionType}}"/>
</div>
```

My .html file :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="actionEditController" >
    <h2 class="marcellus text-center"> EDIT ACTION </h2>
    <div ng-bind-html="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting the rendered data in table from

```
$.hbs
```

.However the `ng-bind-html` does not seem to be appending / binding this value to the HTML . The final output is only

```
EDIT ACTION
```

The rendered data does not display.

Comment: The .success(function (response), response is an object, you need $action = response.data['RESPONSE']; here.

Comment: This works fine. My data is also getting rendered properly as I can see from logging the "table".